# GreenDAO (Android) - Persist object in multiple tables using one insert

Tags: android, sqlite, one-to-many, greendao, greendao-generator

I have the following 3 classes:

1) TvShow

```
@Entity
public class TvShow{

   @Id
   private String uuid;

   private String url;
   private String title;
   ...

   @ToMany(referencedJoinProperty = "tvShowUuid")
   private List<Episode> episodes;
```

2) Episode

```
@Entity
public class Episode{

   @Id
   private String uuid;

   @ToMany(referencedJoinProperty = "episodeUuid")
   private List<Moment> moments;

   //FK
   private String tvShowUuid;
```

3) Moment

```
@Entity
public class Moment{

   @Id
   private String uuid;

   ...

   private String episodeUuid;
```

As you can see the relationship between them is: `TvShow --> oneToMany --> Episode --> oneToMany --> Moment`

Assuming I have a fully populated TvShow object (called tvShow), I am doing the following to add that object to my database:

```
final long rowId = daoSession.getTvShowDao().insertOrReplace(tvShow);
```

This correctly adds the tvShow object to the TvShow table. ***However***, the *Episode* and *Moment* tables are NOT populated at all. The tvShow object has several Episodes and each episode has several moments. I was expecting the other 2 tables to contain that data as well, but they don't.

What am I doing wrong? Am I supposed to loop through each Episode (and in turn loop through each Moment of each episode) and insert them manually instead? =(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I will be wrong, I have had the same problem, but greenDao is not able to persist cascade data - If you say `insertOrReplace(tvShow)` it will not persist list of episodes and list of moments. In order to perform that you have to persist all data separately.

For example:

`TvShowDao.save(tvShows)` OR `TvShowDao.insertOrUpdate(tvShows);`

AND

`EpisodesDao.save(episodes)` OR `EpisodesDao.save(episodes)`

AND

`MomentDao.save(moments);` OR `MomentDao.save(moments);`

In other words, you have to persist all data separately.

I hope so that this helped you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's the approach I ended up using, but I am leaving the question open in case someone comes up with a different approach.

Comment: Can you give me advice, I have problem with foreign key, in your case that will be Episode has not id of TvShow, even though I have added  `@ToMany(referencedJoinProperty = "tvShowId")`?

Comment: Just open your own SO question for that mate. I'll take a look.